# The difference between Raycast and Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I was going through few tutorials and came across Raycast while one used Instantiate to fire a gun and the other used Raycast. I've been programming for a while and I'm still unsure whether I should use Raycast or the latter. Can anyone explain me how it works.

Comment: You might use a Raycast to check where your bullet might go if fired in a certain direction. You could fire a bullet by Instantiating one at your gun's location. Two different approaches, you decide what's best for your game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a big difference. Actually, they couldn't be more different, but I can see the confusion if the first time you learn about them is from the use of firing a gun.

**Raycast:** Imagine a laser. You pick a start point and a direction of this laser and then it returns where the laser hits.

**Instantiate:** You can't really compare this with raycasting at all. Unity uses things called GameObjects. The player is a GameObject, the camera is a GameObject, the terrain is a GameObject. `Instantiate()` simply creates a new GameObject.

---

Using `Raycast()` to fire a gun is pretty straight-forward; start point is the position of the gun, give it the direction, then you get where the gun hits. Using `Instantiate()` to fire a gun would mean creating a GameObject called "bullet" with a RigidBody and a Collider. It would be more performance-intensive but you could add things like bullet drop, wind, ricochet. Although, you might still need to use `Raycast()` to make sure it doesn't go through anything between physics updates, since it's probably moving very fast.

Next time, you should use the [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html) for a question like this.

First thing that came up in Google for ["Unity Instantiate"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) and ["Unity Raycast"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).